# Subset data from entire database each table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have a SQL dump (.sql file) with over 40 tables that has data for x number of different organizations. I want to extract all the related data for one organization and share it with the stakeholder via .sql script or flatfiles. In short, I want to copy the database schema and subset the data from the master database(master) to another database(Specific Org).

Is there an easy and efficient way to subset the data all at once?
The only way I could think of is to perform joins to extract the information. The data model is not star schema, and hence it would be pretty challenging.

I have been provided with just the Data Dump with no additional details. SQL Workbench has the capability to Reverse engineer the Data Model and determine relationship between tables. I am using the tool to help me determine the relationships between tables.

Wanted to check if there is any additional capability within mysql workbench or any other related tool to help extracting a subset of data from the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy method to do this. It must be done carefully using joins. Only you know your data model and the relationships between tables. No tool can know this.

Comment: Thank you for answering. SQL Workbench does have the capability to Reverse engineer the Data Model and determine relationship between tables. To be honest, I am provided with just the Data Dump with no additional details and I am using the tool to help me determine the relationships between tables. Wanted to check if there is any additional capability within mysql workbench or any other related tool to help achieve the same.